# Sending messages beetwen clients by the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, tcp, bearer-token

I have some problem with my project.

I'm trying to create an instant messaging project in c# .net. The client application is made in WPF and the server side in ASP.NET.

User logs in and authorizes with Bearer Token.
Communication is done using HttpClient. From what I've already read on the web, such communication should rather take place via TCPClient, but I don't know how to send a Header with a token.

In addition, I would like the server to inform a specific user about sending him a new message, but I don't know how to do it with HttpListener and whether it should be used in the client application at all.

When I try to make an additional TcpListener connection (the first one was a user login using HttpClient) I get an error saying that each socket and port can only be used once.

Comment: In the context of .Net one of the best solutions is SignalR https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/signalr

Comment: ASP.NET doesn't really do raw TCP connections. It does HTTP(S), or it does web sockets via SignalR. That's about it for protocols. Now, if you're talking about just a .NET application (not ASP.NET) you can of course do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR would would be your best bet for tackling a chat app. I found a tutorial on how to create a chat application using WPF and SignalR.
[SignalChat: WPF & SignalR Chat Application]: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181555/SignalChat-WPF-SignalR-Chat-Application